# Foundation 6 top bar left and right stack when I use a wrap class around top-bar-left and top-bar-right

Tags: html, navbar, nav, zurb-foundation-6

So I'm using Foundation 6 to prototype a project and I'm noticing that top-bar, top-bar-left, and top-bar-right work just as shown on the docs page except when I want to wrap the left and right bars so that they don't touch the sides.

Both top-left-bar and top-right-bar take up the whole width of the top-bar area each and then end up stacking on top of each other. I want them to look like they do in the code pen link below:

(its linked with foundation 6.0.5, and I'm using 6.4.1 - couldn't find a link for that version)
https://codepen.io/mgrosen/pen/RgEVvY

relevant code from app.css

```
.wrap {
width: 90%;
max-width: 1100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-desktop {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-logo {
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.nav-desktop .menu-desktop {
  line-height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-desktop a {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-desktop > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: white;
}

.menu-desktop > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.1);
}
```

relevant index.html code

```
<nav class="top-bar nav-desktop" id="responsive-menu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
      <h3 class="site-logo">Site Logo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
      <ul class="menu menu-desktop">
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('foundation_examples')}}">Foundation Examples</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

That's the actual code I'm using, but when open index.html to look at it (or run my flask application and view it on local host) [this is what i see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG7vY.png) when I'm scrolled all the way to the top of the screen.

Anybody know why this is happening or how I might debug it with dev tools?

Thanks!